# range of sum of cosines of angles of a triangle using vectors?

Tags: vectors, triangles

If $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are sides of a triangle then what will the range of sum of cosines of angles of a triangle. I know that the range is $(1,\frac{3}{2})$. I can approach the answer using trigonometry but have no idea how to get this result using vectors.

someone please tell me what to do. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The upper bound can be obtained as follows:

Let $O$ be the origin of vectors, $\vec{OA}, \vec{OB}, \vec{OC}$ three unit vectors such that $\angle (\vec{OA}, \vec{OB}) = \alpha, \angle(\vec{OB}, \vec{OC}) = \beta$. Then 
\begin{align*}
(\vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OC})^2 &\geq 0  \\
3 + 2\cos \alpha + 2\cos \beta + 2\cos(\alpha + \beta) \geq 0
\end{align*}
and hence
$$\cos \alpha + \cos \beta + \cos(\alpha + \beta) \geq -\frac{3}{2}$$
Since this is true for all $\alpha, \beta$, letting $\alpha = 180^\circ - A, \beta = 180^\circ - B$, we get 
\begin{align*}
-\cos A - \cos B + \cos(360^\circ - (A+B)) &\geq -\frac{3}{2} \\
-\cos A - \cos B + \cos(180^\circ + C) &\geq -\frac{3}{2} \\
-\cos A - \cos B -\cos C  &\geq -\frac{3}{2} \\
\cos A + \cos B + \cos C &\leq \frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: What about the lower bound?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full solution:

Use the identity $\cos A+\cos B+\cos C =1+\frac{r}{R}$ where $r$ is the inradius and $R$ is the circumradius. The Euler inequality is
$$\frac{R}{r}\ge 2\implies 1+\frac{r}{R}\le \frac{3}{2}$$
Clearly, $$\frac{r}{R}> 0$$
Which is where the lower bound comes from. You can show it's tight pretty easily.